# TinyMCE strips out all html when saving using IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, tinymce, internet-explorer-9, tinymce-4

I am having trouble with my TinyMCE text editor in IE9.

For some reason when I submit my changes (php) the html tags are all stripped out when I use IE9.

As far as I can tell all other browsers are fine, but I need to make it work with IE9 (not worried about earlier versions)

Here's my code. The formatting is fine up to the point of saving - it updates the textarea content on keypress.

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <input type="hidden" name="textblock_id" value="123">
    <textarea id="textblock_data" name="textblock_data" ></textarea>
</div>

<script>

var myFont = "Ubuntu=Ubuntu;Comic Sans MS=Comic Sans MS,Architects Daughter,sans-serif;Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Book Antiqua=book antiqua,palatino;Courier New=courier new,courier,monospace;Georgia=georgia,palatino;Helvetica=helvetica;Tahoma=tahoma,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;Times New Roman=times new roman,times;Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva;Verdana=verdana,geneva";
if($('#navigation.website_cms').length) {
    //var myCss = "/assets/css/cms/tinymce.css";
    var myCss = '/cms_manage/get_default_font';
} else {
    if($("#wrapper.primary").length) {
        var myCss = '/assets/css/tinymce.css';
    } else {
        var myCss = '/assets/css/tinymce_secondary.css';
    }
}

$(function(){
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "#textblock_data",
        plugins: "link textcolor paste", // add " table" if needed
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
        paste_retain_style_properties: "*",
        menubar : false,
        statusbar: false,
        toolbar1: "bold italic underline",
        setup: function(editor) {
            editor.on('change', function(e) {
                    $("#textblock_data").html(editor.getContent());
            });
        },
        forced_root_block : false
    });

    $('#textblock_data').closest(".modal").on('hidden', function () {
      tinymce.remove('#textblock_data');
    });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        cleanup : false
});
```